# Set vertical height of vertical axis on Horizontal Stacked Bar Chart

Tags: google-visualization

The following code makes a horizontal stacked barchart that looks like this:

[image]

If I change the **height** attribute to 50 and the **groupWidth** to 40%, the legend disappears and the chart looks like this:[image]

Question 1:  How can I set the height of the bar and still show the legend?
Question 2: How can I get the horizontal and vertical axis to disappear?

What I am really trying to accomplish is a picture like this:

[image]

```js
  <html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          [' ', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
          [0 ,  1000,      400],
        ]);

        var options = {
          isStacked: true,
          width:    200,
          height: 60,
          vAxis: {gridlines: {count: 0}},                    
          hAxis: {gridlines: {count: 0}},          
          bar: {groupWidth: "90%"},
          legend: {position: 'top'}

        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart_div" ></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `chartArea.top` option to move the chart area down and give the legend room to draw:

```
chartArea: {
    top: 15
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/VsBcx/)

Comment: Perfect - that answered the part about the legend.  Do you by chance know how to get rid of the vertical and horizontal axis lines?

Comment: Actually just found it myself: **baselineColor: 'none'**